# Can't boot installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Inspiron 14 3480 laptop

Tags: boot, 20.04, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 3480 installed with windows 10. Erases the OEM OS by installing an Ubuntu 20.04LTS. But after restarting the laptop Ubuntu OS will not load after shutdown.

Tweak some item in BIOS like disabling Secure Boot option. Reinstalled it repeatedly a few times with different option and still it wont load Ubuntu OS. I only got a blank screen.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include a little more detail regarding "won't boot"? Are you seeing specific messages when the system refuses to boot? Is it a black or purple screen? Does the system hang on the Dell/Ubuntu logo? Every little detail may point to a possible cause.